# Mongodb $subtract document value from the next one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have such a collection of documents:

```
{ _id: 1, Meters: { gasmeter: 1000.0 } }
{ _id: 2, Meters: { gasmeter: 1007.0 } }
{ _id: 3, Meters: { gasmeter: 1010.0 } }
```

And I am trying to get the difference between the gasmeter elements as such:

```
{ difference: 7 } // Difference between _id=1 and _id=2
{ difference: 3 } // Difference between _id=2 and _id=3
```

I've tried:

```
db.MeterData.aggregate([{$project: { item: 1, difference: {$subtract: [ {$add: [ "$Meters.gasmeter","$Meters.gasmeter" ] }, "$Meters.gasmeter" ] }}}])
```

But this does not work. I still get the same values.

Any idea how to do that aggregation with mongodb?

Comment: You cannot act on values from different documents in the aggregation framework. For a "small and trivial" sample you can `$push` all documents into an array and use `$reduce` iterating over the array values now in a "single" document result. But what you are really talking about here is more naturally done with "cursor iteration". Being that you simply retain a value from the last document read in the cursor and calculate against the next using that stored value in a variable. Not something you ask a database to return directly.

Comment: I understand but isn't it too costly using the iteration with big data set? (Talking about 100k of documents)

Comment: You are asking for the "difference between each document". It's not like you are asking the server to reduce anything. It's still 100K documents. You only need to return the property that has the value you want you know. This is pretty logical, so you need to think it through. This is not an "aggregation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not entirely sure how you wish to solve the problem (in C# or mongo itself). I've come up with this in Mongo.

```
db.MeterData.find().forEach(
    function (doc) {
    var next = db.Sum.findOne({
            _id: {
                "$gt": NumberInt(doc._id)
            }
        })
    if (next != null) {
        var diff = next.Meters.gasmeter - doc.Meters.gasmeter;
        printjson("{ difference : " + diff + "} - Difference between Id=" + doc._id + " and Id=" + next._id);
    }
})
```

Which returns

`"{ difference : 7} - Difference between Id=1 and Id=2"`

`"{ difference : 3} - Difference between Id=2 and Id=3"`

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: I used a different approach and it was successful. I now can get the incremental values of the data in the same collection. All the credits go to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/43594156/5679487

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)  aggregation operator:

```js
// { id: 1, gasmeter: 1000 }
// { id: 2, gasmeter: 1007 }
// { id: 3, gasmeter: 1010 }
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $setWindowFields: {
    sortBy: { id: 1 },
    output: {
      difference: {
        $push: "$gasmeter",
        window: { range: [-1, "current"] }
      }
    }
  }},
  // { id: 1, gasmeter: 1000, difference: [1000] }
  // { id: 2, gasmeter: 1007, difference: [1000, 1007] }
  // { id: 3, gasmeter: 1010, difference: [1007, 1010] }

  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [{ $size: "$difference" }, 2] } } },
  // { id: 2, gasmeter: 1007, difference: [1000, 1007] }
  // { id: 3, gasmeter: 1010, difference: [1007, 1010] }

  { $set: {
    difference: { $subtract: [{ $last: "$difference" }, { $first: "$difference" }] }
  }}
])
// { id: 2, gasmeter: 1007, difference: 7 }
// { id: 3, gasmeter: 1010, difference: 3 }
```

This:

- starts with a [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)  aggregation stage which adds the `difference` field in each document (`output: { difference: { ... }}`)

  - as an array `$push` of `gasmeter`s (`$sum: "$gasmeter"`)
  - from the specified span of documents (the `window`) which here is the `"current"` document and the previous one `"-1"`: `window: { range: [-1, "current"] }`
- then filters out the first document that doesn't have a previous document (i.e. we can't diff its value with a previous document's value):

  - to do so we simply check that the size of the array produced with the previous stage is 2: `{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: [{ $size: "$difference" }, 2] } } },`
- and finally substracts the 2 values in the array to get the actual difference: `$subtract: [{ $last: "$difference" }, { $first: "$difference" }]`