# MongoDB query to subtract one record value with another

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I was working on fetching the **value** fields of all the records and subtracting it with next record value. 
This is how my records looks like:

```
{
  "name":"abc",
  "value":10
},
{
  "name":"xyz",
  "value":20
},
{
 "name":"pqr",
 "value":30
}
```

And I have gone through these queries to achieve it, but didn't get the desired output.

Query:

```
db.myc.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$value"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        value1: {
            $first: "$value"
        },
        value2: {
            $last: "$value"
        },
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        Output: {
            $subtract: ["$value1", 10]
        }
    }
}]);
```

Got output like :

```
{ "_id" : "abc", "Output" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "xyz", "Output" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "pqr", "Output" : 20 }
```

Desired output I was looking for , first record **value** should remain same which is 10 and next record value(20) should be subtracting with third record value(30). So that all the field values will remain 10. (Input data will always has 10 difference with next data).

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve it ???

Comment: That's not what `$first` and `$last` do. You cannot access the previous or next document if that was what you were expecting. Use a cursor for this type of thing instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn sure, i will try and the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Inputs:

```
    {
         "_id" : ObjectId("5bf52fe30d11f12257d430bf"),
    "name" : "fff",
   "value" : 50
    },
   {
   "_id" : ObjectId("5bf52fe30d11f12257d430c0"),
    "name" : "gd",
   "value" : 60
   },
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bf52fe30d11f12257d430c1"),
  "name" : "ffagf",
   "value" : 70
   }
```

Use the below query to get the desired output:

Note: The highest value will be stored as 0 at the end.

```
  db.myc.find().forEach(
  function(doc){
  var n = db.myc.findOne({_id:{"$gt":doc._id}}); 
  var diff = n.value-doc.value; 
   print(tojson(diff)); 
 });
```

The Output :

```
10
10
0
```

Refer to this answer : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061846/mongodb-subtract-document-value-from-the-next-one)