# How to collect specific samples from MongoDB collections?

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

I have a MongoDB collection "Events" with 1 million documents similar to:

```
{
"_id" : 32423,    
"testid" : 43212,
"description" : "fdskfhsdj kfsdjfhskdjf hksdjfhsd kjfs",
"status" : "error",
"datetime" : ISODate("2018-12-04T15:55:00.000Z"),
"failure" : 0,   
}
```

Considering the documents were sorted based on datetime field (ascending), I want to check them in the chronical order one by one and pick only the records where the "failure" field was 0 in the previous document and it is 1 in the current document. I want to skip other records in between.

For example, if I also have the following records:

```
{
"_id" : 32424,    
 ....
"datetime" : ISODate("2018-12-04T16:55:00.000Z"),
"failure" : 0,   
}
,
{
"_id" : 32425,    
 ....
"datetime" : ISODate("2018-12-04T17:55:00.000Z"),
"failure" : 1,   
}
,
{
"_id" : 32426,
 ....
"datetime" : ISODate("2018-12-04T18:55:00.000Z"),
"failure" : 0,   
}
```

I only want to collect the one with "_id:32425", and repeat the same policy for the following cases.

Of course, if I extract all the data at once, then I can process it using Python for instance. But, extracting all the records would be really time-consuming (1 million documents!).

Is there a way to do the above via MongoDB commands?

Comment: Could you please show enough sample docs and the desired output docs from that sample. Will there always be at least 1 doc with failure = 0 and 1 with failure = 1?

Comment: @Bob :  when you say rows do you mean fields in the document or documents itself ? As records in mongoDB are called documents - so just checking on it.

Comment: @srinivasy thank you for the tip, I just corrected it.

Comment: @Bob : what do you mean by 'where the "failure" field was 0 in the last document and it is 1 in the current document', I'm a bit confused, can you please elaborate once..

Comment: @srinivasy for example, considering the document with "id:32425" (and failure=1), the previous document in the chronical order would be the one with "id:32424" (and failure=0), so I collect the one with "id:32425".

Comment: Ok if you've two documents both have failure :1 and failure : 1 you don't need those two,  failure :0 & failure :1, you need this failure :1 document

Comment: @srinivasy Yes, given that they happen one after the other according to datetime.

Comment: @Bob, as of now I'm not aware of anything on how to solve it, but I will try & post it here if I find a way.

Comment: One trick I've seen to compute differences between documents is temporarily $pushing documents into arrays, doing the calculation/filter with aggregation array tools, and then $unwinding the array again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560777/mongodb-aggregation-query-to-subtract-and-grouping-of-cumulative-value/43594156#43594156 (Depending on the number of failures, it may be simpler to instead do something like grabbing all of the failures, and then for each failure finding the previous document one at a time)